# Does a double siyum occur?

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, siyum

What is the procedure if one happened to finish two masechtas simultaneously? Does a double siyum occur? What would that be, anyways?

Answer (score 4):

The only difference from a normal siyum is that when saying the hadran, you say both - מסכתות ברכות ושבת, for example.

Mazel tov!

Comment: Interesting, makes sense, like when they make the siyum hashas. Do you have any sources?

Comment: As far as I can tell there aren't any in any real sfarim (I've looked a lot for this one), but that's what all of my rabbeim told me to do (though one when I made a siyum on 13 at once my menahel insisted that the 2nd and 3rd time through I just say "כל המסכתות האמורות לעיל"), and what I've seen by a number of talmidei chachamim.

Comment: I recommend you edit your sources from your comment into the answer post. Comments are ephemeral by design.

Comment: @msh210 none of them are what I would call a source; it's not much better than me just saying it stam

Comment: That is indeed what happens when you finish a massekhet which is last in the seder, you massekhet X v'seder Y (see text of hadran in artscroll, e.g., massekhet Horayot)